# Conditional render is not updating with setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I have a form that I would like to update depending on the state of a toggle in that form. Here is my container component with the form:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Create,
  Edit,
  NumberInput,
  SimpleForm,
  TextInput
} from 'admin-on-rest';
import LatLngInput from '../customInputs/LatLngInput';
import UTMInput from '../customInputs/UTMInput';
import UTMSwitch from '../customInputs/UTMSwitch';

export class LocationEdit extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      utmInput: false,
      utm: {
        easting: 0,
        northing: 0,
        isSouthern: false,
        zone: 0
      }
    };
  }

  toggleUTM() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ utmInput: !prevState.utmInput }), () => {
    console.log(this.state.utmInput);
   });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Edit title={<LocationTitle />} {...this.props}>
        <SimpleForm validate={validateLocationCreation}>
          <TextInput source="name" />
          {this.state.utmInput ? (
            <UTMInput />
          ) : (
            <LatLngInput />
          )}
          <UTMSwitch defaultToggled={this.state.utmInput} onToggle={this.toggleUTM.bind(this)}/>
        </SimpleForm>
      </Edit>
    );
  }
}
```

The toggle is supposed to switch between two input fields: `UTMInput` and `LatLngInput`. These are currently pretty similar with the exception of their labels:

UTMInput:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import { NumberInput } from 'admin-on-rest';
const UTMInput = () => (
  <span>
    <Field name="latitude" component={NumberInput} label="Northing" />
    <br />
    <Field name="longitude" component={NumberInput} label="Easting" />
  </span>
);

export default UTMInput;
```

LatLngInput:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import { NumberInput } from 'admin-on-rest';
const LatLngInput = () => (
  <span>
    <Field name="latitude" component={NumberInput} label="Latitude" />
    <br />
    <Field name="longitude" component={NumberInput} label="Longitude" />
  </span>
);

export default LatLngInput;
```

I understand that setState by itself does not guarantee a UI update, which is why I've included the `console.log(this.state.utmInput)` as a callback to the `setState` function in `toggleUTM` (this logs alternating `true` and `false` to the console as expected). I've also tried the other form of setState which accepts a function instead of an object, as the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) suggest. I've even tried using `this.forceUpdate()` after the `console.log(this.state.utmInput)`. None of these have worked.

I've used breakpoints in VSCode and I can confirm that the `setState` function is being called each time I toggle the switch but the conditional (`{this.state.utmInput ?`...) is not being called. I'm using the [`admin-on-rest` framework](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/index.html), although I don't know if this is the issue. I've checked the source code and `shouldComponentUpdate` is not being used in any of the components I've imported from that framework (`<Edit />`, `<SimpleForm />`, `<TextInput />` or `<NumberInput />`).

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: It's probably not the problem (in fact, you said you'd tried it), but the `setState` call in `toggleUTM` is wrong regardless. That **must** use the function form. So may as well fix it: `this.setState(prevState => ({ utmInput: !prevState.utmInput }), () => { console.log(this.state.utmInput); });`

Comment: At first glance, the `utmInput` stuff seems fine (other than the above). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: i doubt on this part: *shouldComponentUpdate is not being used*, if they are not using `shouldComponentUpdate`, then i think component will be `PureComponent` check that also. to verify you can render a dummy div inside `LocationEdit` and check whether that is getting changed or not. like this: `this.state. utmInput ? <div>a</div>: null`

Comment: can you show your import statements in `LocationEdit` file ?

Comment: can you try with declaring a variable, assign JSX values to it conditionally and render it instead of the switch-case? just to confirm if the problem is in conditional behaviour or somewhere else.

Comment: Included import statements and changed the setState call to function form. I'll try using a dummy div now and see if that does anything.

Comment: Using a dummy `div` inside `LocationEdit` the form still doesn't update. I'll look into setting up a runnable example to help demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried putting together an example repo that reproduces the error, but it worked fine in this new example. Turns out, despite my best guess, the Admin On Rest framework was the problem.

Upgrading to version 1.4.0 from 1.3.2 solved my issue.